# Azure Runbook to Start/Stop Virtual Machines

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-automation, azure-runbook

So I have a bunch of virtual machines that are spread across different resource groups and I want to have them shut down/start up according to specific times. I want to make management of this as easy as possible and am trying to find a way to use Tags and Runbooks to accomplish this. The thing is, I want them to be able to start/stop at different times depending on their resource group. So far, I've made tags for all the VM's that all have the same `tag Name` and the `tag value` is the resource group name. How can I make what I'm trying to do as simple as possible? Would a runbook that calls on other runbooks be a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

- There is a tutorial about Start/Stop VMs:
  **[Enable Start/Stop VMs during off-hours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management-enable#define-feature-parameters)**

---

- Or you can write your own scripts in automation by yourself. Think about the logic. Here are some snippets you can refer. About the details of how to use PowerShell command line, it would be better refer to Microsoft docs.

> 1.Get all VMs in your subscription by `$allvms = Get-AzureVM`;
>
> 2.Start the VMs in a specific Resource Group by
>
> ```
> foreach($thisvm in $allvms)
> {
> Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "AzureRG2" -Name "$thisvm"
> }
> ```
>
> 3.Stop the VMs in a specific Resource Group by
>
> ```
> foreach($thisvm in $allvms)
> {
> Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "AzureRG1" -Name "$thisvm"
> }
> ```
>
> 4.link different schedules you want to start up or shut down VMs.
>
> 5.Do not forget to install modules in azure automation.